# LD_PRELOAD-ed shared object traps read(), but not open().. Why?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I'm having trouble intercepting `open()` on Linux (Debian in my case). Here is a minimalistic C source that gets built into a shared object:

```
/* Defines are needed for dlfcn.h (RTLD_NEXT) */
#define __USE_GNU
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int open(char const *path, int oflag, ...) {
    int (*real_open)(char const *, int, ...);
    char *msg;
    va_list args;
    int mflag;

    fprintf(stderr, ">>>>> in open <<<<<<\n");
    real_open = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    if ( (msg = dlerror()) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlsym error: %s\n", msg);
        exit(1);
    }
    va_start(args, oflag);
    mflag = va_arg(args, int);
    return real_open(path, oflag, mflag);
}

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {
    ssize_t (*real_read)(int, void*, size_t);
    char *msg;

    fprintf(stderr, ">>>>> in read <<<<<\n");
    real_read = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
    if ( (msg = dlerror()) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dlsym error: %s\n", msg);
        exit(1);
    }
    return real_read(fd, buf, count);
}
```

The shared object is built using:

```
cc -c -fPIC -Wall funcs.c
cc -shared -o libfuncs.so funcs.o -ldl -lc
```

Now when I try

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libfuncs.so
cat somefile
```

then I only see in the output the trace of `read()` which is `>>>>> in read <<<<<`. I never see a trace of `open()`. I checked what `cat Makefile` does using `strace` and sure enough - both `open()` and `read()` are called:

```
open("Makefile", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)  = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=213, ...}) = 0
read(3, "testrun: libfuncs.so\n\tLD_PRELOAD"..., 32768) = 213
```

Incidentally I checked also with other programs like `od` or `bash`, never got to intercept `open()`. What's going on here? Thanks in advance...

`

Comment: two possibilites. 1) not using the library correctly,  see the man page for an example.  2) the open function is actually a macro to built-in in the OS or the SHELL.

Answer (score 3):

To add to shooper's answer, it seems glibc performs an assembly-level rename from `open()` to `open64()` when compiling an application that calls `open()` with e.g.

```
$ gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 open.c -o open
```

Adding `-S` to the above command and inspecting the assembly source in `open.s` shows that `open64()` is indeed being called. `$ gcc -E ...` shows that it isn't simply a preprocessor-based rename.

The preprocessed source has this bit though, which performs the renaming:

```
extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __asm__ ("" "open64")
     __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (1)));
```

The code responsible for generating that declaration is in */usr/include/fcntl.h*:

```
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
#else
# ifdef __REDIRECT
extern int __REDIRECT (open, (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...), open64)
     __nonnull ((1));
# else
#  define open open64
# endif
#endif
#ifdef __USE_LARGEFILE64
extern int open64 (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
#endif
```

The declaration with the `__REDIRECT` is what's being used here.

Provided that this is the real issue, my guess is that glibc in turn turns the `open64()` call into the `open("Makefile", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)` system call that you see in the `strace`. Since you can only override functions and not the system calls themselves, you should try `open64()` instead like shooper suggested.

(I'm not sure why glibc does it this way by the way, if it's for other reasons than simply to avoid macros.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try "open64" instead of "open"?